# Enable drag drop on a winform application

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, mdi

I would like to enable drag-and-drop feature for my winforms application. The main UI form is an MDI container.

I added the following code to the main form

```
    mainuiform.AllowDrop = true;
    mainuiform.DragDrop += OnDragDrop;
    mainuiform.DragEnter += OnDragEnter;
```

The drag-and-drop does not work in the body of the application and works only on the header of the application.

Then I read that the drag-and-drop should be enabled for each child component then only we can drop a document anywhere on the application ui. This is painful as the various forms in the MDI are created by different teams.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add event handler to the main form (constructor)
2. Add event handler to all child component of the main form (in load event)
3. Add event handler to mdi child and its all children component (MdiChildActivate event)

since I am using DevExpress there are some DevExpress methods (there should be equivalent with winforms).

```
        public MainMdiForm() {
            RegisterDragDropEvents(this);
            MdiChildActivate += OnMdiChildActivate;
        }

        // load event handler
        private void MainMdiFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
            if(sender is XtraForm form)
                form.ForEachChildControl(RegisterDragDropEvents);
        }

        private void RegisterDragDropEvents(Control control)
        {
            control.AllowDrop = true;
            control.DragDrop += OnDragDrop;
            control.DragEnter += OnDragEnter;
        }

        private void DeRegisterDragDropEvents(Control control)
        {
            control.DragDrop -= OnDragDrop;
            control.DragEnter -= OnDragEnter;
        }

        private void OnMdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is XtraForm form)
            {
                // since the same event is called on activate and de active, have observed that ActiveControl == null on de active
                // using the same to de register
                if (form.ActiveControl == null)
                {
                    form.ForEachChildControl(DeRegisterDragDropEvents);
                }
                else
                {
                    form.ForEachChildControl(RegisterDragDropEvents);
                }
            }
        }

        void OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
          // take action here
        }

        void OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // additional check and enable only when the file is of the expected type
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
```

Drag drop works on the application with this code.